Can I use 给 for inanimate objects?
The meaning I want to achieve is "I need to buy some things for my camera" but I'm having a bit of trouble in writing this in mandarin.
I thought of writing 我要买一些东西给我照相机, but I don't know if the use of 给 is correct...
Since 给 is a basic grammar topic I thought I would find more resources with more examples, but all the structures I found for 给 meaning for, the recipients were a living thing (person, animals, etc), so I wanted to know if it can be used for inanimate objects and if not, if it exists a simple way of writing this sentence...
Thanks in advance :)

给 can mean "give (給予/送给)" or "for (為)"

I found for 给 meaning for, the recipients were a living thing

That's incorrect, the recipients have to be living beings only when 给 means "give (給予/ 送给)" You cannot give a desk anything because a desk can't own anything
给朋友生日禮物 = 送生日禮物给朋友 = Give a birthday gift to a friend
给兒子的房間打掃 = 為兒子的房間打掃 = Cleaning (for) son's room

我要买一些东西给我的照相机 = I have to buy something to give to my camera [verb + 给 + object]- (X)

我要给我的照相机买一些东西 = I need to buy something for my camera [给 + object + verb]- (O)



Maybe like  this:
我需要给我的相机买点配件。
I need to buy some accessories for my camera.
It's OK to use 给 here.


I wanted to know if (给) it can be used for inanimate objects

Yes, you can, by adding a pronoun "this/that", or possesive pronoun "my/his/her..." in front of the inanmiate object.
Your original sentence would be fine if modified as  "我要买一些东西给這個/那個照相机" - I am going to buy something for "this/that camera". Simiilarly, you can say - "我要买一些东西给我的照相机" - I am going to buy something for "my camera".
However, "buy something" for an inanmiate object is a very vague statement, preferrabily, the sentence shall be continued with "such as...", or change "something" to more specific terms - "一個鏡頭" or "一些零件/底片".
Note, in verbial conservation, the pronoun can be eliminated with the clear presence of the object, and/or a clear ownership (belong to you/your family), for example,

小王, 给(這張)桌子換張桌布 - 小王, replace the tablecloth for the table.

別忘了给車子加油 - Don't forget fill up the gasloine for the car. (the car belongs to you or shared by you with someone else)

到沃爾瑪給照相机買個腳架 - Go Walmart to get a tripot for the camera. (this is the sole camera belongs to you and/or your family)



It is correct to use 给 as 我要给我照相机买一些东西.
But it is also common 我要买一些东西给我相机 as oral language.
